# Blotchy Mesh Imported from Maya

Tags: mesh, uv

new to Blender but Maya vet.

I exported an FBX to Blender and the mesh came in blotchy.  Can't figure out what's going on.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

The mesh looks like light grey and dark grey camouflage.  Even the texture has a blotchy look to it.  When I originally imported the mesh into Maya, the model had all hard edges, so I softened them in Maya.  Could this be the reason?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to BSE.

It would be a little easier to answer your question if you could provide your blend file ([Including a .blend file](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file)).

However as a guess, this may be an issue with some of your normals facing the wrong way.

To fix this:

- Select your mesh and press Tab to enter Edit Mode
- Press A to select all vertices
- Press Alt+N > Recalculate Outside